# I'm completely new to SQL and can't answer a simple question on an exam

Tags: sql

I'm in the middle of an exam and can't find how SQL works at all.

The exercise is the following: someone owns a flower shop and wants to find on his database how many grasses which price are strictly inferior to 10 he owns.

The example I previously got on another exercise, to find ferns at the time, was:

```
SELECT * 
FROM FLOWER 
WHERE Family = "Fern";
```

I tried to enter the same code to find if I was at least able to get a table with all the grasses, but

```
SELECT * 
FROM FLOWER 
WHERE Family = "Grass";
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM FLOWER 
WHERE Family = "Grasses";
```

didn't work. I tried with GRASS and GRASSES too, none of them led me to any table (it tells me there are no results for this request.)

Furthermore, I don't know how to ask for the price limit.

This is the table I get when the code works. Maybe showing you how it looks might help.
[image: table]

Comment: Beside a small hint to tag the database you are using, try to use single quotes around the string you want to look for, like `'grasses'` instead of `"grasses"`. SQL is often very quote sensitive.

Comment: Ok, appearently you can ignore my first comment. Can you somehow check if you named the column correctly? Is it really `family` and not `familles`? Plus you might want to give us the error your database returns when you try your query

Comment: I just tried to do it, it doesn't work either.

Comment: then try to use `select * from flowers;` this should give you the whole table. If that throws an error too, you have the wrong table name or the connection to your database is faulty

Comment: For the column, I simply translated it since the language used here is english, but I indeed used ```familles``` for the code.

Comment: okay, thanks I'm going to try this

Comment: Try first `SELECT DISTINCT Familles FROM FLEUR`.  That will show you the list of possible types.  It may be that the family name for grass is something different.

Comment: Okay, so I can get all the flowers list when I try what you told me to. Found the "Grasses" category, I'm going to try again with the exact same writing that is given on the table.

Comment: Okay Jonathan, I'm going to check this too, thanks to both of you!

Comment: Indeed, I got all the different types listed on a table! Thanks a lot!

Comment: As a side note: that tutorial teaches you invalid SQL if it accepts `where familles="Pivoine"`.  In standard SQL, `"Pivoine"` is a column reference due to the double quotes, it's not a string constant